# URL Rewriting in Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

I had jsp page where user clicks on submit button where the links goes to Orbeon new data form where user will submit the data and redirected to JSP Page.

But when user clicks on submit button the actual url of orbeon url should be hidden so that user should not aware of orbeon url new data form link. Can u let us know how this can be achieved.

Comment: It seems to me that this is not specific to Orbeon. It's unclear to me what you do when the user presses the Submit button on your JSP. What do you do there? A POST to the URL of the JSP page? Or a POST to the Orbeon URL? Or do you use GET? More details are needed to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're using the `workflow-send` button to send users back to your JSP. When users click the corresponding *Submit* button in the form:

1. The browser does a POST to Orbeon Forms.
2. Orbeon Forms does a POST to your JSP with the XML data filled by users.
3. Your JSP responds with a page, which goes to Orbeon Forms.
4. Orbeon Forms funnels the response to the browser.

This explains why the URL doesn't change, and users see the Orbeon URL with the content generated by your JSP. Orbeon Forms can't get the browser to do the POST directly to your page for a number of reasons, including the fact the browser doesn't have access to the XML (doing so would be a security risk) and that browsers don't know how to POST XML (other than in XHR requests).

If you really don't want users to see the page with the Orbeon URL, your JSP needs to respond with a forward (client-side redirect), which sends the browser to maybe another JSP, which in turn produces the actual HTML you want to show users.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.. 

but problem is Jsp is in one war file and orbeon is in another war file . 

if we use send redirect it will show orbeon url .

if we forward the problem is we cant forward to another url of war file 

Can you help how to achieve this